# my code result in an infinite loop

Tags: ruby

```
puts "enter a number"
x = gets.chomp.to_i
y = 0
while x != 1
  y += 1
  if x % 2 == 0
    x = x / 2
  else
    x = x*3 + 1
  end
  print "#{x} "
end

puts "\nThe number of sequence is #{y+1}"
```

Hi, if I key in negative number or 0, I will get an infinite loop. How do I avoid entering the loop if my number is 0 or negative.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the rule of thumb: in Ruby if you are using `while` loop, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Your condition is redundant. if `x < 0`, then it follows that `x != 1`.

Comment: @mudasobwa while that is true, when the number of iterations are indeterminate as in this question, it is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `x > 1` i.e

```
puts "enter a number"
x = gets.chomp.to_i
# if you want to consider negative as positive then x = gets.chomp.to_i.abs
y = 0
while (x > 1)
  y += 1
  if x % 2 == 0
    x = x / 2
  else
    x = x*3 + 1
  end
  print "#{x} "
end

puts "\nThe number of sequence is #{y+1}"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi previously I got confused with myself, I have changed my question hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Updated my asnswer @roppo

Comment: how about for the case of 0?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

Your code works perfectly well and does exactly what it is told to do:
`while x is not 1 OR x is smaller than 0 do this codeblock`.
If you set x to a negative number, x will never be a positive number, so it runs forever (because x is always smaller 0).

So, the code is correct, but there is a flaw in the logic behind it :)

Comment: Hi previously I got confused with myself, I have changed my question hope it makes sense now.